# javascript d3 selectAll transform to loop

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have this code below. There are two .attr to add to the "path" they use both the same function. Is it possible to transform this code to a loop in which i can only call once my function and use the value for both .attr?

```
            var edges = svgGroup.selectAll('path .edge').data(artifacts).enter().append('path')
            .attr('class', 
                function(d){
                    if (getStatusActive(d.targetName)){
                        return 'edge';
                    }else{
                        return 'edge_grey';
                    }
                }
            ).attr('marker-end', 
                function(d){
                    if (getStatusActive(d.targetName)){
                        return 'url(' + markerLocation + '#arrowhead)';
                    }else{
                        return 'url(' + markerLocation + '#arrowhead_grey)';
                    }
                }                
            );
```

I look for something like this:

```
            for (each element of selectAll / data(artefacts)){
                var result = getStatusAcive(d.targetName);
                //create with result both strings and add them to the attr
                ...
                ...
                element.append('path').attr('class', resultString1).attr('marker-end',resultString2);
            );
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the value of the string depends on the data, you can't replace it like you're wanting to do. You could however compute that string in a separate step, bind it to the data and then use that, i.e.

```
data.forEach(function(d) {
  if (getStatusActive(d.targetName)){
    d.resultString1 = "edge";
    d.resultString2 = 'url(' + markerLocation + '#arrowhead)';
  }else{
    d.resultString1 = "edge_grey";
    d.resultString2 = 'url(' + markerLocation + '#arrowhead_grey)';
  }
});

sel.attr("class", function(d) { return d.resultString1; })
   .attr("marker-end", function(d) { return d.resultString2; })
```